# Css changes not updating in Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, editor

I have created a web site and every time I edit some css styles in Appeareance->editor , changes are not updated. I tryed cache plugins with no effect. Any possible suggestion?

Comment: clear your `minify cache`, then deactivate all cache plugin, if your theme also support Cache, then deactivate that setting for time being, then clear your browser cache and cookies, even better open a `private window (incognito mode)` and load your website in that, then from browser inbuild developer options check the content of `style.css` and see your changes are in their or not.

Comment: Also some hosts (like Siteground, for instance) have server caching that you have to clear separately sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I updated css file from cpanel/public.html/theme/css and NOT from wordpress editor and it worked.Clearing cache can also help.